# accessing instance methods from class method proc

Tags: ruby

I am trying to call a proc on a class but access instance methods from it with an inherited class.  I think some mock code will make more sense :)

```
class Bar
  def self.foo &block
    @foo ||= block
  end
  def foo; self.class.foo.call(); end
  def bar; 'bar'; end
end

class Foo < Bar
  foo do
    bar
  end
end

Foo.new.foo
# NameError: undefined local variable or method `bar' for Foo:Class
```

I want to be able to access the `bar` instance method on the Bar class.  The reason for calling the foo class method with a block from the inherited class is part of the DSL requirement, but any suggestions for a better design would be appreciated.

Comment: The two foos are confusing.

Comment: Why are `new.bar` or making `bar` a class method not good?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev HA! sorry... im not very creative with my contrived code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocks are lexically scoped, including the value of `self`. At the point where the block is defined, `self` is `Bar` and `Bar` doesn't respond to `bar`. You need to evaluate the block in the context of the object (in this case an *instance* of `Bar` and not `Bar` itself) whose methods you want to call. That's what `instance_eval` does:

```
class Bar
  def self.foo(&block) @foo ||= block end
  def foo; instance_eval(&self.class.foo) end
  def bar; 'bar' end
end

class Foo < Bar; foo do bar end end

Foo.new.foo
# => 'bar'
```

Note that all the usual disclaimers about `instance_eval` apply: since you change the value of `self` methods and instance variables that the block author may expect to be available won't be.

Comment: perfect! i was actually playing with instance_eval earlier, but it was not working since I was not using the ampersand to convert it to a proc.  But now it makes sense.  Thanks you!